# Ignoring Hold Object in Anylogic

Tags: anylogic

I'm creating a model of a simple four stage assembly process.  Each work center is preceded by a queue.  I'm setting up options for a push system, a pull system with three units in the queue and a pull system with one unit in the queue.  I've used "hold" objects to control when inventory is released from the queue's based on the pull 3 or pull 1.  In the case of the Push, I want to set the ignore box so the hold logic does not continue.  Is there a statement I can use to "check" the ignore box in the hold object when the user selects the Push processing method at the start of the simulation?

Comment: hold.unblock() is the solution... why would you ignore if you can just unblock forever?... show the logic to see how complicated it is to unblock forever

Comment: Thanks Felipe - I couldn't go quite that direct but it prompted me on a similar avenue.  By the way - I secured and completed both the Discrete Event and Fluid Library courses a few months ago.  The fluid library in particular has been helpful on a different model project.  Carlo